# Rails 5 + Angular File Structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I've been working on including AngularJS into an App I previously had written solely with Rails because I'm wanting to include Material more.

I'm having a couple issues trying to figure out best practices before I develop bad habits.

Traditionally I followed a file Structure for the views similar to that of

```
views
  layout
    file1
    file2
    _template_1
  users
    file1
    file2
    _template_1
  controller1
    file1
    file2
    _template_1
  controller2
    file1
    file2
    _template_1
```

However, as I read more about asset pipeline interfering with Angular etc, they talk about storing templates in `public/template` directory.

Is this a proper process? It took me a bit to un-route Rails enough to test it, I'm finally just on a new test environment to see how I like it.

I'm also curious how you handle Gems: I assume it's a "semi-gray" line where Angular is ALL Front-end, and Rails is ALL back-end (I am aiming for a Single Page style), but what about a gem such as Devise, or OAuth2 etc etc? I assume this incorporates the Model that you would still use a traditional Rails method and bypass Angular?

Welcome any insight - Mostly on the file structure. 
Currently I am also matching the controllers naming structure the exact same,

Ex:

```
app
  assets
    javascripts
      users_controller.js
  controllers
    users_controller.rb
```